# Break from for loop and match exact file name in Python

Tags: python

Here is my code:

```
import os

folderPath= "my images folder path"
pathList = os.listdir(folderPath)
myID = input("Enter Your ID: ")
for path in pathList:
    myIDList = os.path.splitext(path)[0]
    if myID in myIDList:
        print(myIDList)
    else:
        print("Incorrect")
```

The output is printing in the loop but I need exact match of the filename. If I enter half of the filename, it shows that the file exists. How can I fix this?

Comment: You'll want `if myID == myIDList:` (and `myIDList` really isn't a list at all anyway, so maybe rename it to `file_name_without_extension`?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to use a flag variable. and also, **in** operation checks for substrings, which is the reason it shows file exists for partial inputs. use **==** for exact match.

although it seems there are many other issues with this (including iterating over the pathlist), this might help you get started and understand where you made the mistakes

```
import os

pathList = "my images folder path"
myID = input("Enter Your ID: ")
flag = False
for path in pathList:
    myIDList = os.path.splitext(path)[0]
    
    #using strict check instead of 'in'
    if myID == myIDList:   
        #using flag over breaking the loop when result is achieved
        flag = True
        break 
if flag:
    print("correct")
else:
    print("Incorrect")
```

Answer (score 0):

> How can I fix this?

Use an exact equality predicate? `in` is a *containment* operation, it checks that `myIDList` *contains* `myID`.

And since `myIDList` is a string, that's a substring check.

Also... why are you manually iterating on whatever `pathlist` is supposed to be? The entire thing seems rather wrong-headed. If you have a structure of the form `$DIRECTORY/$USER_ID.ext`, you can just compose a path using that (using `pathlib`, or `os.path.join`), then check that that exists / operate on this. The iteration seems entirely unnecessary.